# Error in SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY category ASC' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Site has been working fine for years and all of a sudden I am getting this error. Any help from the experts would be greatly appreciated.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY category ASC' at line 1

Here is the code in question:

```
// SQL injection attack prevention function
$unit_Recordset1 = "";
if (isset($_GET['unit'])) {
  $unit_Recordset1 = GetSQLValueString($_GET['unit'], "text");
}
$category_Recordset1 = "";
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
  $category_Recordset1 = GetSQLValueString($_GET['category'], "text");
}
else $_GET['category'] = "";

// Query builder that create single or multiple AND query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE ";
if(!empty($unit_Recordset1)) {$sql .= " unit = $unit_Recordset1 AND ";}
if(!empty($category_Recordset1)) {$sql .= " category = $category_Recordset1 AND ";}
// Remove the last AND
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
if(!empty($category_Recordset1)) $sql .= " ORDER BY title ASC";
else $sql .= " ORDER BY category, title ASC";


// Query for left nav DISTINCT category values
$sqlnav = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM documents WHERE unit = $unit_Recordset1 ORDER BY category ASC";


mysql_select_db($database_local, $local);

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($sql, $local) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

$Recordset2 = mysql_query($sqlnav, $local) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);
```

Comment: output `$sqlnav` so you'll see the generated query. Maybe there's a trailing `AND` on your condition before the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are flows where `$unit_Recordset1` may be empty. In which case, the following statement:

```
$sqlnav = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM documents WHERE unit = $unit_Recordset1 ORDER BY category ASC";
```

Will evaluate to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM documents WHERE unit = ORDER BY category ASC
```

Which, of course, isn't valid SQL.
You need to add a check against this case too, something down the lines of:

```
$unitClause = "";
if(!empty($unit_Recordset1) {
    $unitClause = "WHERE unit = $unit_Recordset1 ";
}
$sqlnav = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM documents $unitClause ORDER BY category ASC";
```

Comment: If $unit_Recordset1 is empty then there will not be 'where' clause at all. So  will it not return all the distinct values

Comment: @IndraKumarS I don't understand your comment. If there is no `where` clause, all the records from the table will be returned, and then the `distinct` operation would be applied to them. Where's the problem?

Comment: Suppose if `unit` can be empty values, then where unit = '' will return values which is different from without where condition

Comment: @IndraKumarS The entire code assumes that `unit` cannot have an empty value and that an empty `$unit_RecordSet1` means you should drop the condition on `unit`, from the very first line.

Comment: No... it can have empty values. He declared it on the top of the script. And moreover the error is because of his $sqlnav query where he directly includes $unit_Recordset1 which is a string and that has to be encapsulated with single quotes

Comment: Wherever it's empty, it's omitted from the where clause. Wrt it being a string, I see no reference to it anywhere in the question or the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66972/discussion-between-indra-kumar-s-and-mureinik).

Comment: Wherever it's empty, it's omitted from the where clause.... How do you say like this?  And As far as $sqlnav query is concerned there is no if clause to include or omit where clause

Comment: @IndraKumarS by reading the code, of course. Look for earlier occurrences of `!empty($unit_Recordset1)`.

Comment: @IndraKumarS Thank you gentlemen. I really appreciate the responses from both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Your $sqlnav  query should be like this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT category FROM documents WHERE unit = '$unit_Recordset1' ORDER BY category ASC
```

encapsulate variable $unit_Recordset1 with single quotes